# IOS/iPhone sample code for selecting a location via placename &/or map via use of Google Maps API?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Any IOS/iPhone sample code for selecting a location via placename &/or map via use of Google Maps API?

So an example of letting the user select a location via user of both:
 - typing in location & letting Google Maps API attempt to find location and/or
 - moving placemarker on a map
 - so for example you could type a place and get close on the map, then adjust the precise location with the map
 - end result would be Lat,Long

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are referring to is forward geocoding and unfortunately apple has not provided an api for it. However, there is the next best thing, a third party api. Check out this project, I used it successfully in two projects, works great: https://github.com/bjornsallarp/BSForwardGeocoder

Make sure you include the files necassary so that you can include BSForwardGeocoder without error. Then, simply make the class you want to use it in a BSForwardGeocoderDelegate, and implement the following two protocol methods in your class:

```
-(void)queryAddress
{
  // Initialize member BSForwardGeocoder object
  if (forwardGeocoder == nil) {
    forwardGeocoder = [[BSForwardGeocoder alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
  }

  // send the request

  [forwardGeocoder findLocation:@"Saint Paul, MN"];
}
```

and:

```
-(void)forwardGeocoderFoundLocation:(BSForwardGeocoder *)geocoder
{   
  /*
   * BSForwardGeocoder delegate method. Receives the callback upon geocoding data gather   completion.
   */
  if (forwardGeocoder.status == G_GEO_SUCCESS) {

    int searchResults = [forwardGeocoder.results count];

    for (int i = 0; i < searchResults; i++) {

      // See the sample project code fore other useful location properties...
      // Here I retrieve the returned lat and lon.

      Result *location = [forwardGeocoder.results objectAtIndex:i];
      mLatitude = location.latitude;
      mLongitude = location.longitude;
    } 
  } else { 
    NSString *message = @"";

    switch (forwardGeocoder.status) {
        case G_GEO_BAD_KEY:
            message =@"Bad Api Key";
            break;

        case G_GEO_UNKNOWN_ADDRESS:
            message = @"Address Not Found!";
            break;

        case G_GEO_TOO_MANY_QUERIES:
            message = @"Too Many Queries";   
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Information" 
                                                    message:message
                                                   delegate:nil 
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" 
                                          otherButtonTitles: nil];  
    [ alert show ];
    [ alert release ];  
  }
}
```

This would return the latitude and longitude of Saint Paul, Minnesota using the great library provided by sallarp.

If you want to drag annotations around the map and get their coordinate info this is possible as well, you need to make your class a mkmapview delegate and implement the `mapView:annotationView:didChangeDragState:fromOldState:` method. In your implementation, first check to see if newState is equal to mkAnnotationViewDragStateEnding, if so you can get its coordinate info via the annotationView.annotation.coordinate property. Of course you need to set your annotation views draggable property to YES. If you wanted, you could fire these coordinates in NSString format off to google via the BSForwardGeocoder query method and get it's associated info.

Greg

Comment: thanks - I'd come across this in parellel - what it doesn't quite do/show is how to update the location (i.e. adjust the lat/long) based on moving the marker on the map...not sure if this is possible? i.e. move marker (drop pin) on iphone/ipad map and then it updates the lat/long value?

Comment: I'd be interested to know...Has Apple implemented search yet, or do we still need this third party library?